# What field contains copyright info in EXIF?

Tags: exif, pyexiv2

How can I add copyright information to an image using gexiv2? I've read [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2/PythonSupport) but couldn't find which field I need to edit for this.

Comment: http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html

Comment: So your question actually is: "What field contains copyright info in EXIF?"

Comment: @ThomWiggers guess that may be more appropriate.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Do you want to evolve that into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exiv2 library provides a [comprehensive list](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) of Exif tags available to you as defined by the [Exif 2.2 standard](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF).

You'd need to modify `Exif.Image.Copyright` in particular. The tag ID is "**0x8298**".

Answer (score 0):

You  can set exif tag information.
Here a sample code

```
import pyexiv2

metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata("your_image.jpg")
metadata.read()

metadata["Exif.Image.Copyright"] = "Copyright, Harun ERGÜL. All rights reserved."

metadata.write()
```